# Return records of last 6 months

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below is my SQL statement

```
DECLARE @dStart datetime ,
    @dEnd  datetime

SET @dEnd = GETDATE()
SET @dStart = DATEADD(mm, -6, @dEnd)

Select * from MyTable
Where TheDate Between @dStart AND @dEnd
```

This will return all the records from today minus 6 months data.

But I want this months data plus only the previous 5 months data.

Currently it will return records from March as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
DATEADD(mm, -6, @dEnd)
```

You might use

```
dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @dEnd) - 5, 0)
```

This will truncate date to first of current month and substract five months from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @date datetime
declare @months int
declare @year int
set @months=month(GETDATE())
set @year=month(GETDATE())
set @date=getdate()
(Select * from MyTable Where TheDate Between (01/@months-5/@year) AND (01/@months/@year) ) union (Select * from MyTable Where TheDate Between (01/@months/@year) AND @date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @dStart datetime ,
    @dEnd  datetime

SET @dEnd = GETDATE()
SET @dStart = DATEADD(mm, -4, @dEnd)
```